# How to clean up / transform JSON data when reading it in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

What is a clean and idiomatic way to clean up (transform) a a badly formed JSON array of hashes, structured like the one below, assuming that the keys inside the hashes are always going to be well formed?

In this example, the postal codes and phone numbers are in different formats, and there is a key/value pair street_address that is in only one of the hashes. What I want to do is to pass all the postal codes into a helper parses postal codes, pass the phone numbers through a phone number cleaner, and pass the street address, if it's present, into its own parser. I want to preserve the structure of JSON array, just normalise the values.

```
[{      "name": "Person 1",
    "postal_code": "VXXXS",
    "phone_number": "(111)093910",
}, 
{      "name": "Person 2",
    "postal_code": "VX-XXS",
    "phone_number": "++(111)093139",
}, 
{      "name": "Person 3",
    "street_address": "1 Something Rd",
}]
```

I was thinking of iterating through each array element, and then using a switch statement as follows:

```
json.each do |hash|
 hash.keys do |key|
  case key
  when "postal_code"
    hash[key] = postal_code_parser(hash[key])
  when "street_address"
    hash[key] = street_address_parser(hash[key])
  when "phone_number"
    hash[key] = phone_number_parser(hash[key])
  end
 end
end
```

but this is kind of ugly, and I thought that this probably a common problem enough that there's exists a clean and more efficient way to solve it. I still find ruby overwhelming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to call the values by their keys explicitly:

```
json.each do |hash|
  hash["postal_code"] = postal_code_parser(hash["postal_code"]) if hash.key?("postal_code")
  hash["street_address"] = street_address_parser(hash["street_address"]) if hash.key?("street_address")
  hash["phone_number"] = phone_number_parser(hash["phone_number"]) if hash.key?("phone_number")
end
```

The `if` at the end of each line means that the code will not be called if the value for that key is not set.

If you want to make it more generic and dynamic, you can keep a list of parsers per key:

```
parsers = {"postal_code" => :postal_code_parser,
           "street_address" => :street_address_parser
           "phone_number" => :phone_number_parser}

json.each do |hash|
  parsers.each do |key, parser|
    hash[key] = send(parser, hash[key]) if hash.key?(key)
  end
end
```